# Download without opening in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have below code to download an image:

```
 anexoDownload(id){
     window.open(this.global.UrlGlobal + '/api/v1/cadastros/despesa/download-anexo/' + id, '_self');  
 }
```

However when run on the device it opens the browser and downloads. This behaviour is only on the device. How to do this download without opening it in the browser?

Comment: What else would you expect `window.open()` to do except open a browser window?

Comment: I tried with the `<a href="{{xxx}}"></a>` tag but it also opens the browser. I need it to download without opening the browser

Comment: You will probably need to use Ionic Native File or something similar, to choose a destination and write the file

Comment: Okay. How do I download it?
`return this.file.getFile(this.global.UrlGlobal + '/api/v1/cadastros/despesa/download-anexo/' + id, 'main.jpeg', { create: false })`